# Why is Captcha folder so large?

Tags: magento2, captcha

There is 12GB worth of something in the 'captcha' folder of this Magento 2 install.

I cannot browse the folder in cPanel's File Manager. Can anyone elaborate as to what is in this folder, why it might be so large, and how one might go about making it smaller?

[image: cPanel Disk Usage]
[image: Database Entries for Cron Jobs]

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the cron Job is running.

Take a look: `vendor/magento/module-captcha/etc/crontab.xml`

```
<job name="captcha_delete_expired_images" instance="Magento\Captcha\Cron\DeleteExpiredImages" method="execute">
        <schedule>*/10 * * * *</schedule>
</job>
```

As we can see, Magento set up a cron to delete captcha images automatically. (This cron will execute at every 10th minute.)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer! This file and the job both exist, is there a way to determine if this job is successfully doing it's job?

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/setup-cron-magento-2/ and http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: Based on the documentation I have read, this should run the cron manually via SSH `php bin/magento cron:run --group="captcha_delete_expired_images"`, which I have done, and still no luck. I fear this might be a fruitless endeavour, thanks for your help though! Much appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the table `cron_schedule`? There are any info?

Comment: Have checked `cron_schedule` and it looks like none of them have ever been run, except for `captcha_delete_expired_images` which I ran manually... I have added a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Check the error log after running the captcha cron manually.

Comment: Hey, just ran the cron again and had a look in 'log' and 'report', but cannot see anything related. I did notice that the file called `magento.cron.log` is completely empty, not sure if this is a good sign, haha.

Comment: What about Magnto 1.9? We don't have the crontab.xml file...

Comment: @Peanuts I have checked my Magento 1.9.3 version, I saw the cron job: app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml