# Magento 1.9.3.4 huge CAPTCHA images folder

Tags: captcha

We have 150.000 captcha images on media/captcha/base folder.
We are using Magento 1.9.3.4.
We know there should be a cronjob to clear unused captcha images, but I don't know how to find it, or how to find the log to detect the problem.

I have gone through this threads/posts but they are for Magento 2:

- [Why is Captcha folder so large?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182047/why-is-captcha-folder-so-large)
- https://www.mynameisvolkert.com/12-000-000-unxepected-magento-captcha-files/
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Captcha-Base-folder-Large-Capacity/td-p/107265

We don't have this folder structure to check our cronjob is there: vendor/magento/module-captcha/etc/crontab.xml

What can I do to solve this situation?
Thanks,

Comment: Captcha crontab configuration available in this location magento\app\code\core\Mage\Captcha\etc\config.xml

Comment: Thanks very much my friend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`media/captcha/base` is getting big with usage.  Magento 1 is has a setting in `app/code/core/Mage/Captcha/etc/config.xml`  to clean the folder periodically but this only happens when the cron is setup to work properly.

You will need to add a cronjob to run the magento cron every 5 minutes.

in a linux hosted magento you would do something like this

```
# open cron
crontab -e 
# add relevant task
*/5 * * * * sh /home/users/mydomain/www/cron.sh >> /home/users/mydomain/www/var/log/cron.log 2>&1
# close file and save
```

if this not working you can clean the folder directly

```
# open cron
crontab -e 
# add relevant task
*/5 * * * * rm /home/users/mydomain/www/media/captcha/base/* -rf
# close file and save
```